# Whats the median of $\$4800$ and $\$12000$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out what the median income would be for a year if I made between $\$4800$ and $\$12000$ in the year.

Comment: List all of your cash flows from highest to lowest, pick the middle value. If there is no middle value, average the two closest to the middle. Or group your cash flows by month, whatever makes sense for what you are trying to find

Answer (score 4):

Because your list has only two elements, there is no distinction between the calculations of the mean (average) or median (middle) scores.

Normally when you calculate a median, you arrange your list from lowest to highest and then find the middle score. If the number of elements in your list is odd, the middle score will be unique and that is your median. If the number of elements on your list is even, then there will be two scores in the middle. In that case you average them and report that as the median.

Since your list has two elements the two middle scores are $\$4800$ and $\$12000$ and we average them to get $\$8400$ as the median.

You calculate the mean by adding up the list and dividing by the number of elements. But for your list, it turns into the exact same calculation as the median.

Comment: This depends on the model you have for the values. For a linear model, the arithmetic mean would be correct. For other models, you might take the geometric mean, harmonic mean, or see what I mean.

Comment: That is true. But someone who is asking this kind of question wouldn't appreciate or necessarily understand that distinction, I think. No offense to the original poster.